# Save as using EPPlus?

Tags: c#, epplus

Does any one know how to use the package.Saveas function?

```
package.SaveAs(tempFolderPathAlt + saveas + ".xlsx");
```

At the moment this is underlined in red with the following error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.SaveAs(System.IO.Stream)' has some invalid
>   arguments

At the moment i'm saving the file in the following way.

```
FileStream aFile = new FileStream(tempFolderPathAlt + saveas + ".xls",    FileMode.Create);
byte[] byData = package.GetAsByteArray();
aFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
aFile.Write(byData, 0, byData.Length);
aFile.Close();
```

But this way the package remains open and i cant work with files it has used.

The save as will close the package properly, but its not accepting my file path.

---

**Edit**

I tried this:

```
using (FileStream aFile = new FileStream(tempFolderPathAlt + saveas + ".xlsx", FileMode.Create))
{
    byte[] byData = package.GetAsByteArray();
    aFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    package.SaveAs(aFile);
    //aFile.Write(byData, 0, byData.Length);
    aFile.Close();
}
```

But Get the following error?

Package object was closed and disposed, so cannot carry out operations on this object or any stream opened on a part of this package.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**The package will be closed & disposed after you call any of functions** `GetAsByteArray`, `Save`, `SaveAs`. That is the reason why you got message

> *Package object was closed and disposed, so cannot carry out operations on this object or any stream opened on a part of this package.*

The solution is that after the saving you call `Load` function to continue processing on excel file. Or if you just want to get both ByteArray & FileOutput, I'm sure with you they both are same.

You can read data after have saved file to the disk:

```
string path = @"C:\test1.xlsx";
Stream stream = File.Create(path);
package.SaveAs(stream);
stream.Close();

byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

Or you can save data to disk after get the ByteArray:

```
byte[] data = package.GetAsByteArray();

string path = @"C:\test1.xlsx";
File.WriteAllBytes(path, data);
```

Answer (score 9):

I came looking for the answer to this but the existing answers were not clear to me.
Here is what I did using EPPlus and `System.Windows.Forms`:

```
ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(xlsTmpFileName)

// Populate the Excel spreadsheet here.

SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    xlPackage.SaveAs(fs);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I dont know from which version onwards but EPPlus's `SaveAs` method accepts a `FileInfo`. So you could do something like this:

```
using (var app = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(inputPath)))
{
    //process
    app.SaveAs(new FileInfo(outputPath));
}
```

Unlike the `Save` method `SaveAs` method **overwrites** file as well in case file name already exists.

Answer (score 1):

`SaveAs` would be accepting your `aFile` Stream.

You can find out such things yourself by looking at the function signature: `SaveAs(System.IO.Stream)`. It takes a `Stream`. Passing a `string` cannot possibly compile so you have to somehow make up a useful `Stream` (which you did).

Comment: Can i set the save as function to save to a file path?

Comment: No because you cannot give it a path. You can give it your FileStream though.

Comment: Try removing "package.GetAsByteArray()". Did you close the package somewhere before saving it? Anyway, the code you posted is the right approach. You might want to ask a new question concerning the new error message.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the surplus `package.GetAsByteArray` call and you should solve it.

I just ran:

```
using (FileStream aFile = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\asdf.xlsx", FileMode.Create))
{
    aFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    package.SaveAs(aFile);
    aFile.Close();
}

// See here - I can still work with the spread sheet.
var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Single();
```