# How do I save an ExcelPackage to a local path without opening Excel?

Tags: vb.net, epplus

I'm trying to output a ExcelPackage created using EPPLUS to a file path without Excel actually opening up the file. I've got the below code right now...what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
 Dim FileName As String = "C:\Temp\" + CurrAcct + ".xlsx"
 Dim Result As New MemoryStream()
 xlPackage.SaveAs(Result)
 Context.Response.Clear()
 Context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-      officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
 Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName + ".xlsx")
 Result.WriteTo(Context.Response.OutputStream)
 Context.Response.End()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a FileStream to save it to the local disk.

Here is a stackoverflow example: [Save as using EPPlus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912912/save-as-using-epplus)