# Writing an Excel file in EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

I have been stuck on this for days and despite all of the help out there, none of these solutions have been working for me. What I want to do is create an excel file using the EPPlus library with some basic data in it that I am pulling from a stored procedure. This is the code that I have in my ExportDocument.cs file:

```
public static ExcelPackage CreateExcelDocument(int [] arr)
{
    String path = @"D:\temp\testsheet3.xlsx";
    //FileInfo newFile = null;
    /*if (!File.Exists(path + "\\testsheet2.xlsx"))
    newFile = new FileInfo(path + "\\testsheet2.xlsx");
    else
        return newFile;*/
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("testsheet");
        ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "Number of Used Agencies";
        ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "Active Agencies";
        ws.Cells["D1"].Value = "Inactive Agencies";
        ws.Cells["E1"].Value = "Total Hours Volunteered";
        ws.Cells["B1:E1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;

        int x = 2;
        char pos = 'B';
        foreach (object o in arr)
        {
            String str = pos + x.ToString();
            ws.Cells[str].Value = o.ToString();
            if (pos > 'E')
            {
                pos = 'B';
                x++;
            }
            pos++;
        }
        package.Save();
        return package;
    }
}
```

All the commented code is different things that I have found on the internet to try. Note that this a school organization and we are not using MVC. I am then using the code behind file to pull this method like this:

```
protected void GenerateReport(Object o, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["reportSession"] = ddReport.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
    int [] arr = new int [ReportRepository.GetAgencyCounts().Count];
    ReportRepository.GetAgencyCounts().CopyTo(arr, 0);

    ExcelPackage pck = ExportDocument.CreateExcelDocument(arr);
    /*try
    {
        byte [] data = ExportDocument.CreateExcelDocument(arr).GetAsByteArray();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.BinaryWrite(data);
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", data.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }*/

    /*var stream = new MemoryStream();
    pck.SaveAs(stream);

    String filename = "myfile.xlsx";
    String contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
    {
        Inline = false,
        FileName = filename
    };
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    stream.Position = 0;

    return File(stream, contentType, filename);*/

    /*Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
    Response.TransmitFile(Path.GetFullPath(file.Name));
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();*/

    /*Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Sample2.xlsx");
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();*/
}
```

Again note that all the commented code is things that I have found from various sources that have not worked.

So I am not getting any errors but when I click the button on my application to execute the code behind method, nothing is happening. It is loading and it runs through but there are no files created, nothing is opening up. This is the first time I have ever used EPPlus and I am not wholly familiar with exporting things to excel programmatically so I feel lost here.

Are there any suggestions that you guys have? I would be happy to clarify any points that I have not hit upon fully as well.

Comment: you've declared a `path`, but I don't see it used in the code (ignoring the commented bits). How are you telling excelpackage to save it to a location?

Comment: the path variable currently is not being used. The way it is written now, it is the ExcelPackage package object is using its save method and then I am calling that ExcelPackage in the codebehind file where I am writing it out using Response.BinaryWrite(byte[] arr). That was the last method I tried anyway. Using that, there is no need for a path.

Comment: Additionally, I also tried saving the file to a path and then opening it from there but I ended up getting the same issue I am having now. The file was never created and my code did not bomb or error out

Comment: OK - so [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13376386/326543) suggests that you need to use a stream to get content from `package` to file. Could you see if this works for you?

Comment: I tried that too. It is commented out in my ExportDocument.cs file. I get the same thing as before. No files are created and nothing shows up

Comment: Hmm that is really strange, I'll try to setup something quick and dirty, to play around and see if I can replicate this.

Comment: @DustinLeatherman -- I find myself with very similar issues -- did you ever get this bit of source working?

Answer (score 36):

Have you looked at the samples provided with EPPlus?

This one shows you how to create a file
http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ContentSheetExample

This one shows you how to use it to stream back a file
http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample

This is how we use the package to generate a file.

```
var newFile = new FileInfo(ExportFileName);
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{                       
    // do work here                            
    xlPackage.Save();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call xlPackage.Dispose() before the end of using block, because the whole purpose of a using block is to call a dispose method on an object created in the parentheses.

Comment: True, however it was pinched from the examples.

Comment: Use `SaveAs(FileInfo)` method to save to a new location. It also overwrites if file name already exists, unlike `Save` method which throws. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38036089

Answer (score 15):

It's best if you worked with `DataSet`s and/or `DataTable`s. Once you have that, ideally straight from your stored procedure with proper column names for headers, you can use the following method:

`ws.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(<DATATABLE HERE>, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light8);`

.. which will produce a beautiful excelsheet with a nice table!

Now to serve your file, assuming you have an `ExcelPackage` object as in your code above called `pck`..

```
Response.Clear();

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + sFilename);

Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 10):

If you have a collection of objects that you load using stored procedure you can also use `LoadFromCollection`.

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("test");

    worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(myColl, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium1);

    package.Save();
}
```