# .NET Excel output causes file you're trying to open is in diff format than specified ext

Tags: c#, .net, excel, xls, excel-interop

I have written a function to export db data to Excel file. I formatted the data to xml first and then I used the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application() to output the data to .xls file.

However, when I open the newly created xls file, the following alert: "The file you are trying to open is in a different format than specified by the file extension......" is displayed.
[image]

Although clicking yes opens the file normally, how do I modify my code so that the alert will not be displayed?

Here is the code of my function.

```
private void exportToExcel(string fileName,DataTable dt)
{
    StringBuilder dXML = new StringBuilder();
    dXML.AppendLine(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
                        <Workbook xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'
                            xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'
                            xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel'
                            xmlns:ss='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'
                            xmlns:html='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>");
    dXML.AppendLine(@"<Styles>
                        <Style ss:ID='fontSetup'><Font ss:Size='8'/><Alignment ss:ShrinkToFit='1' ss:WrapText='1'/></Style>
                        <Style ss:ID='hyperlink' ss:Parent='fontSetup'> <Font ss:Size='8' ss:Color='#0000FF' ss:Underline='Single'/> </Style>
                        <Style ss:ID='header' ss:Parent='fontSetup'>
                            <Font ss:Color='#FFFFFF' ss:Bold='1'/>
                            <Interior ss:Color='#333399' ss:Pattern='Solid'/>
                        </Style>
                      </Styles>");
    dXML.AppendLine("<Worksheet ss:Name='Students'>");
    dXML.AppendLine("<Table>");
    dXML.AppendLine("<Column ss:Width='200'/>");
    dXML.AppendLine("<Column ss:Width='100'/>");

    dXML.AppendLine("<Row>");
    dXML.AppendLine("<Cell ss:StyleID='header'><Data ss:Type=\"String\">Student Name</Data></Cell>");
    dXML.AppendLine("<Cell ss:StyleID='header'><Data ss:Type=\"String\">Address 1</Data></Cell>");
    dXML.AppendLine("</Row>");
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        dXML.AppendLine("<Row>");
        dXML.AppendLine("<Cell><Data ss:Type=\"String\">" + IntranetUtility.TrimNull(row["std_name"]) + "</Data></Cell>");
    oXML.AppendLine("<Cell><Data ss:Type=\"String\">" + IntranetUtility.TrimNull(row["addr"]) + "</Data></Cell>");
        dXML.AppendLine("</Row>");
    }
    dXML.AppendLine("</Table></Worksheet></Workbook>");
    var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempFile, false))
    {
        writer.Write(dXML);
        writer.Close();
    }

    // output xml as xls
    using (var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application().WithComCleanup())
    {
        object missingVal = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        excelApp.Resource.Visible = false;
        excelApp.Resource.DisplayAlerts = false;
        excelApp.Resource.AlertBeforeOverwriting = false;
        using (var excelAppWorkbooks = excelApp.Resource.Workbooks.WithComCleanup())
        {
            using (var excelWB = excelAppWorkbooks.Resource.Open(tempFile, missingVal, missingVal, missingVal, missingVal, missingVal, missingVal, missingVal, missingVal, missingVal, missingVal, missingVal, missingVal, missingVal, missingVal).WithComCleanup())
            {
                excelWB.Resource.SaveCopyAs(fileName);
                excelWB.Resource.Close(missingVal, missingVal, missingVal);
                //excelWB.Resource.Close(true);
            }
        }
        excelApp.Resource.Quit();
    }
    File.Delete(tempFile);

}
```

Say I call the function like this: 
exportToExcel("C:\Folder\test.xls", dataset.Tables[0])

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is in `filename`? You pass it to the function, but don't include it anywhere in your post. If the extension is `.xml`, Excel is expecting an XML file. If it's .xlsx, it expects an actualy .xlsx file (which is actually a zip file), and if you're passing .`.xls`, it expects a specific binary format. What extension are you passing in `filename`? You're not specifying any output format conversion in your call to `SaveCopyAs`.

Comment: the fileName is C:\folder\test.xls

Comment: But you're not saving an .xls file, because you're not specifying any conversion. You're just saving XML with a different extension. (Open the file you think is XLS format with Notepad. You'll see it's XML.) Changing a file's extension does not convert the file to that format.

Comment: Look at the top rated answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651272/writing-an-excel-file-in-epplus and do that instead. Toss out all that code you wrote