# Create 2007/2010 Excel file and save to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc, epplus

I am using the EPPlus package to export an Excel 2007 file from a datatable, but I want to save the Excel file that I have created on the server. I am using this method:

```
private string SaveExcelFile(DataTable dt)
        {
            string reportName = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss-fff") + ".xlsx";

           Response.Clear();
           Response.Charset = "";
           Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
           Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
           Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
           Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + reportName + "\"");

           using(ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
           {
             ExcelWorksheet wsDt = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
             wsDt.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true, TableStyles.None);
             wsDt.Cells[wsDt.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

             //Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
             string filePhysicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/PeriodsReports/" + reportName);
             System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePhysicalPath, pck.GetAsByteArray());
           }

           Response.Flush();
           Response.End();

           return reportName;
        }
```

After Excel has saved, I got this error:

> Excel can't open the file because the file format or file extension is
>   not valid

Comment: Don't you think that error also have to be posted in the question ?!

Comment: i edited my question, sorry, i changed the line of error, but i faces another one

Comment: It's strange behavior ... I had `excel can't open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid` when i used `WriteAllText` and it was resolved by `WriteAllBytes`. Are you sure that you open file which was saved by `WriteAllBytes` method ? Maybe you missed up something?

Comment: I don't know the reason of this error If you are sure that you didn't miss up anything. You can try just another approach from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912912/save-as-using-epplus)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `WriteAllText` for binary files.(and excel is binary file)
Try this instead

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePhysicalPath, pck.GetAsByteArray());
```

Comment: i used this line but when opening saved excel file, this message appears : excel can't open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid